# What is the function of acetic acid as a solvent in EAS reactions?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds

I saw acetic acid being used in two reactions:

  1.

[image]

2.

[image]

I was asked to predict the outcome of the first reaction but I couldn't, because nitration requires generation of $\ce{NO2+}$ which in turn **requires an acid stronger than nitric acid**. (acetic acid is weaker)

I would like to know how exactly is $\ce{AcOH}$ participating in these two reactions. **Is it supporting the generation of electrophile?** **If yes, then how?** I couldn't find any relevant information on the net. The second reaction is from Clayden's book and it doesn't highlight the role of $\ce{AcOH}$ there.